# How to write a server by c that can change the progress of video/audio on the server?

Tags: c, web-services, sockets, server, video-streaming

How to write a server by c that can change the progress of video/audio on the server?

I write a server program by c, but when I using javascript to change `currentTime` of `<video>` element which getting source from this c server, the video will always start at begin.

The code of responding file request is as below:

```c
void send_file()
{
  // count file length
  int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
  int file_len = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

  // send http header
  if (strcmp(type, ".mp4") == 0) {
    sprintf(type, "video/mp4");
  } else {
    // ...
  }
  sprintf(head, 
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
      "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
      "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      , type
      , file_len
      );
  send(c_sock, head, strlen(head), 0);

  // send file content
  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

  int delta = 0;
  while (delta < file_len) {// read by lines
    memset(msg, 0, 4096);
    int size = read(fd, msg, 1024);
    delta += size;
    // send(c_sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    send_helper(msg, size);
  }

  close(fd);
}

void send_helper(char *content, int size)
{
  while (size > 0) {
    int delta = send(c_sock, content, size, 0);
    if (delta <= 0) return;
    size -= delta;
    content += delta;
  }
}
```

and I'm using

```c
  while (1) {
    c_sock = accept(s_sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (c_sock != -1) {
      int nread = recv(c_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    }
  }
```

to receive the request from browser.

When requesting a `mp4` file, the request and response header will be

```
GET /source/1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
Range: bytes=0-
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 105270886
```

When using the `apache` server, the headers will be

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 08 Aug 2020 11:04:55 GMT
If-None-Match: "6464e66-5ac5bb1097630"
Range: bytes=0-4653055
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 05:09:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 08 Aug 2020 11:04:55 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "6464e66-5ac5bb1097630"
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 58392576-105270885/105270886
Content-Length: 46878310
```

Is this problem (video always start at begin) only because the request and response head(for example `Content-Range`)? How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server must declare that it accepts a range with `Accept-Ranges: bytes` and then it must process the `Range` header from the client, provide only the requested part and declare this in the `Content-Range` header - exactly like you see in the requests send to Apache.

For the exact but necessary details please follow the actual standard, i.e. [RFC 7233 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another problem:
When I using `Partial Content` protocol, my browser will send many `Range Requests`, but my server is still sending the preview response and my program shows that the pipe was broken.
So should I need to terminate preview `Partial Content` translation and start a new one? Do you know how to do it using `c`? (When using `Partial Content`, my program only get the first request from my broswer (and then crashed), and I don't know how to receive the follow-up `Range Requests`)

Comment: @嬲你屋里娘: unfortunately, *"... how to do it using c ..."* is way too broad since you actually have a wide range of problems. This is not really a problem of how to do a particular thing in C but you have a missing understanding of HTTP, a missing understanding of what Broken Pipe means and how to deal with it (there are many questions here about this topic) and also no capability to handle multiple requests at once in your server.